# $x^4-t^4$ irreducible over $\mathbb{C}(t^4)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Question from Cox's book: Show that $x^4-t^4$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}(t^4)$.

Q1. **Is there an elegant way to show this?**

If $x^4-t^4$ has a root in $\mathbb{C}(t^4)$, then it factors as $(x-a)(x^3+ax^2+a^2x+a^3)$, where $a \in \mathbb{C}(t^4)$. Then we have $a^4 = t^4$.
$a$ is a rational function in $t^4$, so write $a = \frac{p(t^4)}{q(t^4)}$ where $p(x), q(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.
Then $p(t^4)^4=q(t^4)^4t^4$,
and I think one can show that this is a contradiction.

The other case is if $x^4-t^4$ has a quadratic factor $(x^2+ax+b)$. Then I show that $x^4-t^4 = (x^2+b)(x^2-b)$, form the equation $-b^2 = t^4$, and get a contradiction in a similar way to above.

Q2. **Can I check that this way is on the right track?**

Comment: $x^4-t^4=(x^2+t^2)(x-t)(x+t)$ but $t,-t,it,-it\not\in\Bbb C(t^4)$

Comment: You are looking at $x^4-u$ over $\Bbb{C}(u)$, with $u=t^4$. Gauss' Lemma says it suffices to prove it's irreducible over $\Bbb{C}[u]$. Have you heard of Eisenstein's criterion?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I guess I can show that $t \notin \mathbb{C}(t^4)$, and that for all pairs of factors $(x-i^k t)$, the product is not in $\mathbb{C}(t^4)$ too, and so conclude that there is no linear factor and no quadratic factor?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I see, so it remains to show that $u$ is prime in $\mathbb{C}[u]$. i.e. $(u)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{C}[u]$. But I suppose this is clear since if $f(u)g(u) = u$, then comparing degrees either $f$ or $g$ is constant, and the other term is then a constant multiple of $u$?

Comment: Correct. That's all there is to it. You may consider posting it as an answer as well. For more feedback.

Comment: Ok I have just done so, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We write $u = t^4$. Then the question is to show that $x^4-u$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}(u)$.
By Gauss' Lemma, it suffices to prove it is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}[u]$.

We first show that $u$ is prime in $\mathbb{C}[u]$.
i.e. $(u)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{C}[u]$.
So suppose $f(u)g(u)= h(u) \cdot u$ for $f(x), g(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$. Then either $f(u)$ or $g(u)$ has constant term equal zero.
So either $f$ or $g$ is divisible by $u$, and hence in $(u)$.
Therefore, $u$ is prime.

By Eisenstein's criterion, $x^4-u$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[u]$.

Many thanks to Jyrki!

**Edit:** Saw this elsewhere: To show $(u)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{C}[u]$, we can use $\mathbb{C}[u] / (u) \cong \mathbb{C}$ is a field. And so $(u)$ is maximal ideal and hence prime.